# JQuery Draggable + Droppable with the dragged object clipping because of the Dropzone overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm implementing Jquery UI on my site. A quick description is that I have a series of images that can be dragged and resized. I'm trying to get it to be dropped in a div that has an overflow property: hidden. The idea is that once dropped in the div, it is clipped so it doesn't go beyond the div. At the moment it isn't working at all Please see code below:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#collage" ).draggable().resizable({autoHide: true});
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({tolerance: "touch"});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you putting your script code inside a $(document).ready() {} function? If not the elements #collage and #droppable will not have been rendered when the js is run.

Comment: can you explain what " it isn't working at all" means, exactly?

Comment: The .resizable() functionality allows a user to resize an element. I'm not sure why you are using it, but just saying it will not cause your image to be clipped to the size of the container, in case that's what you hoped.

Comment: Hi Nikkoran, the script is going to go into $(document).ready() {} function. What I want to achieve is #collage is both draggle and resizable (as it is already) and when placed into #droppable (with overflow:hidden) it will crop any part of it (#collage) that extends past the #droppable div.